# Power query,Check if value in column A contains one of values in column B

Tags: powerquery

I want to make,
Check if value in column A contains one of values in column B then value is comes from column B value else blank.
I wrote a function similar to below and i woke this function on add invoke custom function but i have different tables and needs lots of effort writing and updating them.
I tried many things but i have no result.
If you can help,i will be happy.Thanks much

```
= (Text)=>
if Text.Contains(Text.Upper(Text),"PRIME B360M-D") then"PRIME B360M-D"else
if Text.Contains(Text.Upper(Text),"PRIME B360M-K") then"PRIME B360M-K"else ""
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you .  Create a function named Contains as below

```
(string as text, list as list) =>
let  Spot = List.PositionOf(List.Transform(list, (substring) => Text.Contains(string, substring)),true,1)
in if Spot<0 then null else list{Spot}
```

It looks for an instance where the string contains a match for an item in the List and then returns that item from the list.  If there are more than one match, it returns the last one. No matches returns a null

Add custom column to your table similar to below, which uses function to check each instance of column A against the complete list of items from Column B

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"PreviousStep", "Custom", each Contains([A],Table.Column(#"PreviousStep","B")))
```

Answer (score 3):

M's standard library includes `List.Contains` and `Table.Contains`. Seems appropriate to use either of them.

If I understand your code correctly, when comparing each value in column `A` to all values in column `B`, you want to make a case-insensitive, partial match (since you use `Text.Upper` and `Text.Contains` in the code in your question).

---

**Using standard functions**

Code below shows examples for how you'd use `List.Contains` or `Table.Contains`. Use whichever one you think is best for you:

```
let
    initialTable = Table.FromColumns({{"soft cat", "doG", "fast nun", "long jOg", "big dog", "gullible fish"}, {"time", "slow", "jog", "Dog", "fish", "rambo"}}, type table [A = text, B = text]),
    oneApproach = Table.AddColumn(initialTable, "usingListContains", each if List.Contains(initialTable[B], [A], (x, y) => Text.Contains(y, x, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) then [B] else ""),
    anotherApproach = Table.AddColumn(oneApproach, "usingTableContains", each if Table.Contains(initialTable, [B = [A]], {"B", (x, y) => Text.Contains(y, x, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)}) then [B] else "")
in
    anotherApproach
```

which gives me:

[image: Using standard functions]

Ignoring case-sensitivity, `doG` and `big dog` (in column A) partially match `Dog` (in column B) and therefore the output columns (`usingListContains` and `usingTableContains` aren't blank). Same for `gullible fish` (in column A) and `fish` (in column B).

I'm assuming this is the matching behaviour you're trying to achieve (in your own table).

---

**Using a custom function**

If you find the code a bit hard to follow, you could simply things by creating a custom function (see `containsElseOrBlank` below and give it a better name if you can):

```
let
    initialTable = Table.FromColumns({{"soft cat", "doG", "fast nun", "long jOg", "big dog", "gullible fish"}, {"time", "slow", "jog", "Dog", "fish", "rambo"}}, type table [A = text, B = text]),
    containsElseBlank = (someTable as table, columnToCheck as text, columnToLookIn as text, newColumn as text) =>
        let
            comparer = (x, y) => Text.Contains(y, x, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
            containsFunc = (someValue) => Table.Contains(someTable, Record.FromList({someValue}, {columnToLookIn}), {columnToLookIn, comparer}),
            newColumn = Table.AddColumn(someTable, newColumn, each if containsFunc(Record.Field(_, columnToCheck)) then Record.Field(_, columnToLookIn) else "")
        in newColumn,
    customApproach = containsElseBlank(initialTable, "A", "B", "usingCustomFunction")
in
    customApproach
```

which gives me:

[image: Using custom function]

which I think is the same as columns `usingListContains` and `usingTableContains` (in the previous image). But this approach only requires you to pass arguments to `containsElseBlank` in the right order (and then the function internally handles the rest).

---

Another approach might be to use `Table.NestedJoin` and then check if the result of the join is an empty table or not, but you'd also need to specify how the equality comparison should be done (assuming it lets you specify this).