# Power Query - Is item new to curent month

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a database of employee lists for each month, I want to know how many new employees were hired each month. For this, I assigned a code to each employee, one with the date of the current month and the name and another with the date of the previous month and the name. So, I used a formula to look for the code of the previous month in the column of the code of the current month, if it does not find the value, it returns an error (#N/A) and it would mean that it is a new employee. Therefore, it has a conditional that if it finds any value it is equal to 0 and if it does not find anything (#N/A) it is 1.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHyjN.png)

The problem is that the database is huge and I have it in Power Query but I don't know how to use this formula there.

I already have the employee codes in Power Query but I don't know how to search for an element in the entire column. I tried with this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59504340/21520053) but got no result. I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Please add your sample data as copiable text along with expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had two columns, **Date** and **Name**,  this calculates the delta column for you (does the Name exist on the last Date of the prior month) in powerquery.  You don't need any of the other columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Name", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","Delta", (x)=>  
    if x[Date]=Date.From(List.Min(#"Changed Type"[Date])) then 0   // results for first dates on list
    else  1-Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each Date.AddDays(Date.StartOfMonth(x[Date]),-1)=[Date] and [Name]=x[Name])))
in  #"Added Custom"
```

[image]